# What design pattern to apply for case?

Tags: php, python, design-patterns

I have a table with over 100 columns. Clicking on each column header I can filter by provided parameters.

For example, clicking over header: `name` the input field is appeared allows to filter by name.

So, it can be different filter, by one field and some composite fields.

I tried to avoid linear case using `if` conditions like:

```
if($type == "name") {
   //
} else if ($type == "age") {
  //
}
```

I think it should be strategy and factory pattern to create instance of concrete search class? What do you think?

Comment: How do you know the set of valid values to filter by? Are they database columns (are all database columns valid as filters?), are they stored in an array or some other way?

Comment: For example field `name` is string value in database. But price is float value. And filter by price allows to set range from,to. So, it can be differently filter's behavior

Comment: determine the data type of the field and use that to control behavior

Comment: You'll have to create a mapping - either dynamically from your table's column's and their types, or as an array with `fieldname => [.... settings ...]` values.